# Solr - Aggregate Term Frequency by Group

Tags: solr, lucene, lucidworks

Let's say I have the following set of *grouped* websites crawled and indexed in Solr (latest) :

```
{
    "id":"1",
    "domain": "http://www.category1website1.com",
    "domainGroup": "Group 1"
},{
    "id":"2",
    "domain": "http://www.category1website2.com",
    "domainGroup": "Group 1"
},{
    "id":"3",
    "domain": "http://www.category2website1.com",
    "domainGroup": "Group 2"
}
```

I'm looking for a result set that will give me the term frequency in each individual domain but also the *aggregated* term frequency of that search term (aggregated by domainGroup).

Researching this has lead me to 3 possibilities:

1. [Can be done with Facet Pivot](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.solr.user/81520)
2. [Can be done with Facet + Term Frequency Vectors](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Facet-and-totaltermfreq-td3963006.html)
3. [Cannot be done](http://qnalist.com/questions/4406912/aggregate-termfrequency-on-result-grouping-field-collapsing)

1 and 2 are different and I'm not sure which would work for me, or worse, neither via "option" 3.

Sorry if it's not clear. I'm trying to retrieve the frequency of the "search term" but I also need the frequency aggregated by domainGroup field. In other words I need to search ALL domains for "search term" in one request and retrieve the frequency of "search term" in NOT ONLY the individual domains (the default), but also the aggregated frequencies for all domainGroups (so the sum of term frequencies in all domains under the same domainGroup).

Comment: Just to make sure, your search term query involves another field, eg. "content", and you need these term frequencies on that particular field?

Comment: it is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to retrieve the frequency of your "search term"? If that is the case we are not talking about "term vectors"

Comment: also 1st and 2nd possibility are same

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear. Yes, I'm trying to retrieve the frequency of the "search term" but I need the frequency aggregated by `domainGroup` field. In other words I need to search ALL domains for "search term" in one request and retrieve the frequency of "search term" in NOT ONLY the individual domains (the default), but also the aggregated frequencies for all domainGroups (so the sum of term frequencies in all domains under the same domainGroup).

Answer (score 0):

I think the Facets with Term frequency Vectors is what you need.
Try a query like this:

```
http://something/solr/select/?qt=tvrh&q=query:http://www.category2website1.com&tv.fl=query&tv.all=true&f.id.tv.tf=true&facet.field=domainGroup&facet=true&facet.limit=-1&facet.mincount=1
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't enough to help me, this query (or similar one) is already linked in my post however I'm not at the point where I'm testing out queries already. I need a more definite/detailed answer as the links I posted were not enough to make me understand